# How to override a get_bloginfo function in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function, overriding

```
function custom_get_bloginfo( $show = '', $filter = 'raw' ) {

    switch( $show ) {
            case 'description':
            $output = "my description";
            break;

            default:
            $output = get_option('blogname');
            break; 
    }

        return $output;

}

add_filter('get_bloginfo', 'custom_get_bloginfo', 1, 2);
```

i used above code its not work..

Answer (score 8):

get_bloginfo function supports two filters but only if second argument "filter" is set to "display" i.e.

```
get_bloginfo('name', 'display');
```

So if you wish to use this for some plugin, it will not be of much use.

Filters that can be used:

- bloginfo_url (this one is for all options that return urls)
- bloginfo

Usage:

```
add_filter('bloginfo_url', 'custom_get_bloginfo', 10, 2);
add_filter('bloginfo', 'custom_get_bloginfo', 10, 2);

function custom_get_bloginfo($output, $show) {
    switch( $show ) {
        case 'description':
            $output = 'my custom description';
            break;
        case 'name':
            $output = 'custom name';
            break;
    }

    return $output;
}
```

**UPDATE:**
If you just wish to replace site description you can do this:

```
add_filter('option_blogdescription', 'custom_option_description', 10, 1);
function custom_option_description($value) {
    return 'custom description';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I understand it now, the better way to do it is to edit your header.php and look for bloginfo( 'description' ) then change it with custom_get_bloginfo() then add you can use this to your function.php

```
function custom_get_bloginfo(){
switch( $show ) {
case 'description':
$output = "my description";
break;

default:
$output = get_option('blogname');
break; 
}
return $output;
}
```

Comment: yes i know description can change via settings->General. my exact need to override a get_bloginfo function

Comment: Are you going to use this on a theme or plugin? Thanks